# A novel/book equivalent of the term off-screen

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

**Off-screen** can be used to describe events in a movie or tv show. For example,

> "Harry's father dies off-screen"

What term or phrase can I use if I'm talking about events in a book?

> "Harry's father dies ----"

Same question for **on-screen**.

Comment: Do you refer to the meaning *in private life*?

Comment: @Josh61: No. I'm talking about something like off-page. When the event doesn't take place before the reader but is established through devices like characters conversing about it.

Comment: I'd just use with *offscreen* or *offstage*. It's a metaphor, but the meaning is obvious and I don't see any better alternatives.

Comment: @PeterShor: The meaning is obvious indeed, but without context, readers may assume I'm talking about the movie version rather than the book version (for properties that have both).

Comment: I don't understand the concept of important things to a plot not being mentioned. What does it matter what else happens?

Comment: When you say, "*the event doesn't take place before the reader but is established through devices like characters conversing about it*" does such conversation entail involved description of these events or merely passing reference, or a blend of the two?

Comment: @LittleEva: Either of the two. Like "Where's Joey?" / "He left town." This conversation could end here or go on. But as long as the scene where Joey leaves isn't shown, we'd say Joey leaves offscreen. What do we say if it happens in a book?

Comment: The linked references included in the response advocating usage of the theatrical idiom “off-stage,” as a “*novel/book equivalent of the term off-screen*”, indicate that the “off-stage” events referred to in the Greek theater were not merely alluded to via passing remarks between characters but rather were communicated to the audience in detailed descriptions of those events communicated by the chorus or via a messenger-speech which traditionally follows important offstage action in Greek tragedy.

Comment: From the link: "At the culmination of the play [Oedipus the King], Oedipus discovers his wife and mother Jocasta dead and gashes his eyes out with her brooch-pins. Yet rather than showing Oedipus as he performs this awful deed, Sophocles keeps him out of sight and allows the chorus to describe the act."

Comment: @LittleEva: You've given it a lot of thought

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we had the (silver) screen, we had a *stage*.

Something that was not visible to the audience happened [**offstage**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/offstage), which freedictionary describes as:

> **adj.** 1. Situated or taking place in the area of a stage that is invisible to the audience.
>   **adv.** 2.b. Behind the scenes; not visible to the public: The meetings between the leaders took place offstage.

I see no problem applying this to a book, the *stage* idiom being quite commonly understood and quite adaptable (offstage can also refer to non-theater settings, meaning *in private*, as opposed to the part of one's life that takes place “in the spotlights”.)

Comment: IMO, The usage of offstage today pertains more to sense 2 you described above. As in, 'an actor known offstage by another name.'

Comment: @Tushar: that may be because in main-stream media, _theater_ is not the most common subject. If you read about theater, _offstage_ is commonly used, e.g. [here](http://thoughtemporium.org/tragedy.htm) or [here](http://www.usu.edu/markdamen/ClasDram/chapters/073gktrageur.htm). See also Jon Hanna's answer to [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97788/literary-device-frequently-referenced-object-which-never-appears). — I read that sense 2 as applying to theater, by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, and one for which I've never heard the answer (at least that I can recall). You could perhaps describe this as events occurring "***outside the narrative or discourse.***"

Answer (score -1):

*Harry's father dies in a **/sidestory/back scene/,** off the main narrative /flow/.*

*Harry's father dies in a **/backstory/back scene/**,* off the main narrative flow.*

where
 [backstory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backstory)

Also, one could consider

**off-camera**, just as good as the "off-stage" mentioned by others

or

**off-page**.

Comment: Dying in a backstory (or sidestory, whatever that is) isn't the same as dying off-screen. 'Off the main narrative' is closer, but it doesn't appear to be a widely used phrase. Plus, it's a mouthful.

Comment: @Tushar: One could consider __off-camera__, just as good as the "off-stage" mentioned by others, or __off-page__.